# Pandas how to apply a function to groupby().first()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a df,the code is:

```
  df = """
      ValOption  RB test contrat
    0       SLA  4  3    23
    1       AC   5  4    12
    2       SLA  5  5    23
    3       AC   2  4    39
    4       SLA  5  5    26
    5       AC   3  4    52
    6       SLA  4  3    64
    0       SLA  4  3    23
    1       AC   5  4    12
    2       SLA  5  5    23
    3       AC   2  4    39
    4       SLA  5  5    26
    5       AC   5  4    52
    6       SLA  4  3    64
  
    """
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s+')
```

output:

```
       ValOption  RB  test  contrat

    0       SLA   4     3       23
    1        AC   5     4       12
    2       SLA   5     5       23
    3        AC   2     4       39
    4       SLA   5     5       26
    5        AC   3     4       52
    6       SLA   4     3       64
    0       SLA   4     3       23
    1        AC   5     4       12
    2       SLA   5     5       23
    3        AC   2     4       39
    4       SLA   5     5       26
    5        AC   5     4       52
    6       SLA   4     3       64
```

Now I group it and get the first by:

```
df_u=df.groupby(['RB','test']).first()
```

output:

[image]

Then I want to apply a function to each row,and for some reason I have to use pd.apply() function:

```
def func(row):
    v1=row['RB']*3
    v2=row['test']-1
    return v1+v2

df_u['new_col']=df_u.apply(lambda row:func(row), axis=1)
```

Notice:In real business the function is very complicated and long,so I need to use pd.apply()

Then I get an error:

```
KeyError: ('RB', 'occurred at index (2, 4)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `reset_index` to access the row 'RB' & 'test'. Use `.values` to set values to `new_col`:

```
df_u['new_col'] = df_u.reset_index().apply(func, axis=1).values
print(df_u)

# Output:
        ValOption  contrat  new_col
RB test                            
2  4           AC       39        9
3  4           AC       52       12
4  3          SLA       23       14
5  4           AC       12       18
   5          SLA       23       19
```

**Update**

> How to return the new_col to the original df?

```
df = df.merge(df.drop_duplicates(['RB', 'test'])
                .assign(new_col=func)[['RB', 'test', 'new_col']],
              on=['RB', 'test'], how='left')

# Output
   ValOption  RB  test  contrat  new_col
0        SLA   4     3       23       14
1         AC   5     4       12       18
2        SLA   5     5       23       19
3         AC   2     4       39        9
4        SLA   5     5       26       19
5         AC   3     4       52       12
6        SLA   4     3       64       14
7        SLA   4     3       23       14
8         AC   5     4       12       18
9        SLA   5     5       23       19
10        AC   2     4       39        9
11       SLA   5     5       26       19
12        AC   5     4       52       18
13       SLA   4     3       64       14
```

**Update2**

> The reason I drop_duplicates is for saving time,make it faster
> because the length of row is 60k,if I apply to each row,it spend lots of time,instead if I drop the duplicated first,I don't need to apply to each row,I directly assign the value to the same column value row

Apply is a for-loop like, use vectorization:

```
df['new_col'] = (df['RB']*3) + (df['test']-1)
```

**Performance**

For 140,000 records, the operation above took 361 µs:

```
%timeit (df1['RB']*3) + (df1['test']-1)
361 µs ± 9.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For 14 records (it's not a mistake), the previous operation took 935 µs:

```
%timeit df.drop_duplicates(['RB', 'test']).apply(func, axis=1)
935 µs ± 5.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you so much,one more question ,how to return the new_col to the original df ?

Comment: Do you want to set the values only for each first instance or for all rows?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if it's what you expect?

Comment: Thank you so much again,but instead of NaN,how to put the real  new_col value in the duplicated rows.The reason I drop_duplicates is for saving time,make it faster ,but in the final each row should have a new_col value.

Comment: Are you sure saving time? Filter, apply, and restore is probably slower than apply on the whole dataframe.

Comment: Yes, because the length of row is 60k,if I apply to each row,it spend lots of time,instead if I drop the duplicated first,I don't need to apply to each row,I directly assign the value to the same column value row.The problem is the function is very long and complicated,so the less apply row ,the better

Comment: I updated my post. Even if I found a solution to fill nan with right values, it will ever be slower than vectorization. Check the performance part.

Comment: Thank you for your update,I have part of code is using vectorization,but in another part I have some logic like: for i in range(df['RB'],136):  and logic like df[str[df[['RB']]] for each row,this makes me trouble for 2 weeks ,that is the reason why I only use pd.apply for these logics,my business logic is extremely  complicated.I know pd.apply is the slowest way

Comment: I updated again my first update. Can you check it please?